# how can I render a whole image on the background?

Tags: html, css

I  tried these

```
*background-size: auto auto;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 50vh;*
```

problem is it is displaying cropped image , I wanted the whole image to be displayed.

Comment: You need to change the `background-size` to `cover`

Comment: As was said, the background-size to cover or, if you aren't concerned with potential distortion:  background-size: 100% 100%;

Comment: I have tried both, Didn't display the full Image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't show a full image exactly on all devices/viewports because their aspect ratios differ from that of your image.

`background-size: cover` will cover the viewport but maintain aspect ratio, so if your image is for example very wide compared to the viewport height some of the image will get cropped at the sides.

If it is important that you actually show the full image as stated in the question then use `background-size: contain` but this will show space at top or sides if the aspect ratios of the viewport and your image are not the same.

To actually show the full image AND cover the entire viewport you can set `background-size: 100% 100%;` but this is often not satisfactory because it will stretch your image in one dimension or the other to fit which will make it look rather odd in most cases.

Comment: did you mean background-size, not background--image in some of these ones?

Answer (score 0):

Here try this
I used a image from [Unsplash](https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531315630201-bb15abeb1653?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60)
use `background-size: cover` for full image and `background-position: center`

```css
body {
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531315630201-bb15abeb1653?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Let me know if it doesn't work for you

Comment: actually I wanted the whole image to be displayed , a portion of the image is displayed here. That's where I'm struggling.

Comment: could you please share the image, I want to try something.